# How do you crop a PNG image in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, crop

I have successfully managed to extract a skin patch from a facial image. However; for my task, I don't need the bottom eye and eyelash part. Is there a way to crop the following png image from the top at a slight angle? The resultant image should be in PNG format. I want to crop the following original image to the desired image:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEEbM.png)

[Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdggc.png)

Comment: Have you considered using ImageMagick a.k.a. PythonMagick? It sounds like it might work for you: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this. Assuming you know the angle, you can rotate the image such that the red line becomes parallel with the x-axis, then crop it up above. Then rotate it back. That might introduce some black pixels on the lower left  of the red line. Because images eventually have to be square. Is that something you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Method no2: if you know the pixels on the red line, or you can acquire them somehow, for each pixel, set ever pixel to its left as transparent ( (0,0,0,0) for an RGBA representation). Then crop the image above from what the y-axis value of the lower right corner is.

Comment: I can't apply method one as yeah I am trying to avoid any extra black pixels and the resultant image shouldn't be a square as I need to pass this image through an AI model to detect acne, need all the skin area which is in an irregular shape, not a square. For 2nd method, unfortunately, I don't know the pixel values. Is there a way to calculate them?

Comment: I guess you'll have to draw a white triangle over the unwanted part. As you don't appear to have any coordinates it looks like you'll have to use GIMP or Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the color values of the line of which you want to crop above of, you can do something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

for i, j in zip(*np.where(np.all(img == [0, 0, 253], 2))):
    img[:i, j] = 0

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Explanation:

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Read in the image:

```
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
```

3. Loop though the indices of the image where the BGR value of the pixel at the indices is the BGR value of the line's color:

```
for i, j in zip(*np.where(np.all(img == [0, 0, 253], 2))):
```

4. Set all the pixels before the outer index at the inner index to black. If you were to visualize it it would be drawing black vertical lines one by one:

```
    img[:i, j] = 0
```

5. Show the resulting image:

```
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but the red line is to show the area which I want to crop, I drew it for this question to tell people what I want to crop, I won't be having this line in my picture as the skin patches will be extracted automatically and I don't want the eyelash part in the patch. Sorry if I was unclear, is there any other way to just crop the image from the top portion and obtain the result in the same PNG format?

Comment: @user10114711 Can you post the original image that you want to crop from?